# Session: Why use mode="SQLServer"?

Tags: session

I'm really looking for feedback here. Why would you want to use

```
 <sessionState mode="SQLServer" ... blaw blaw blaw....
```

Here, session is loaded from a database...it can allow a user to, say, recover from a power outage, where the user comes back to a web application and their current state is retrieved, if not past the session expiry time...

Why not just make up a class and load it on ResolveRequestCache and save it on UpdateRequestCache?

Why go to the trouble of perhaps even setting up a separate SQL server to use Session attached to a database?

R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving session information to the database adds support for using multiple web servers connected in a farm, since you then have connected and shared storage between them. So it's really just dependent on what you're looking to do. If you're going to be happy forever and ever, stick with something local that'll likely take less work to implement. If you're worried about scalability, go with something that will let you scale when you need to.